# Python - confused about callable and constructors

Tags: python

I'm looking at Python patterns from [faif/python-patterns](https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/creational/abstract_factory.py), but I have no idea when to use(or pass) a class name without parenthesis ().

**Original code:**

```
import random

class PetShop(object):

    """A pet shop"""

    def __init__(self, animal_factory=None):
        """pet_factory is our abstract factory.  We can set it at will."""

        self.pet_factory = animal_factory

    def show_pet(self):
        """Creates and shows a pet using the abstract factory"""

        pet = self.pet_factory()
        print("We have a lovely {}".format(pet))
        print("It says {}".format(pet.speak()))


class Dog(object):

    def speak(self):
        return "woof"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Dog"


class Cat(object):

    def speak(self):
        return "meow"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Cat"


# Additional factories:

# Create a random animal
def random_animal():
    """Let's be dynamic!"""
    return random.choice([Dog, Cat])()


# Show pets with various factories
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # A Shop that sells only cats
    cat_shop = PetShop(Cat)
    cat_shop.show_pet()
    print("")
```

**But if I do this, it will throw an error.**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # A Shop that sells only cats
    cat_shop = PetShop(Cat())
    cat_shop.show_pet()
    print("")

TypeError: 'Cat' object is not callable
```

What makes it only accept callable? And I know an instance is not callable, but how a class name is callable?

Comment: A callable is an object that implements `__call__`. An object `f` is a callable if `f(*some_or_no_args)` makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PetShop` takes a class (which is callable) as the constructor argument.

`Cat()` creates an instance of `Cat`, which itself isn't callable.

So you need to pass in the class `Cat` to `PetShop` instead of the `Cat()` object:

```
# A Shop that sells only cats
cat_shop = PetShop(Cat)
cat_shop.show_pet()
print("")
```

Comment: yes what makes me confused is that why PetShop only takes a class (or callable) instead of an instance

Comment: class is used to create objects. You can't create an object by calling that object (it might not be callable).